# Windows 7 - VPN - Need to download another user's credentials while connected

Tags: windows-7, domain-controller

I'm an admin on a Windows 7 machine, and it must be connected to the domain for a user to login for the first time.  I can login when it's off the VPN since my credentials are cached.

I need to tell Windows to allow another user to login to the machine with their credentials cached, but they can't login for the first time because the VPN disconnects when I logout.

Is there a `net use` command or something so that I can say "go find user DOMAIN\xyz123 on the DC and cache their credentials so they can login locally while the DC is not availalbe"?

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a net use command or something so that I can say "go find user DOMAIN\xyz123 on the DC and cache their credentials so they can login locally while the DC is not available"?`

No there isn't. You can however use "Switch User" to log on as the user while leaving yourself logged on and connected to the VPN. This should allow the user to logon to the domain, whereby caching their credentials. I've done this before many times.

Comment: `Switch User` is greyed out on the laptop, so I cannot switch use that when I'm logged in.  I'm assuming that's a group policy thing...